# PyMongo: Closing the cursor inline when using count()

Tags: python, pymongo

Right now I have a piece of code like this:

```
[{'id': i, 'title': somedict[i]['title'] % db.somecollection.find(somedict[i]['query']).count()} for i in somedict.keys()]
```

It works, however, I don't like the fact that I don't close the cursor returned by `find(...)`.
Is there any way to modify this code so it calls `close()`, keeping it inline?

Comment: With the standard implementation of Python, [the garbage collector will close the cursor for you](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.close). Do you have special requirements that you want to close it manually ?

Comment: Not really, I do use standard implementation. But I would like to know if that's possible or not.

Comment: Is it required to have it inline? Why don't just split it into 3 lines: cursor initialization, your list comprehension line and `cursor.close()`?